# Request laravel from operation in controller

Tags: php, laravel, database, controller, sum

I want a request a data from operation i made in controller, when i try my code the output total is null.

I try this code

```
$total += $request->jumlah_pinjaman;
$data = [
        'tanggal' => $request->tanggal,
        'no_bukti' => $request->no_bukti,
        'jumlah_pinjaman' => $request->jumlah_pinjaman,
        'uraian' => $request->uraian,
        'user_id' => $request->user_id,
        'total' => $request->$total
        ];
dd($data);
```

And the output is

```
array:6 [
  "tanggal" => "2023-11-29"
  "no_bukti" => "KSB231129290"
  "jumlah_pinjaman" => "100000"
  "uraian" => "garapan"
  "user_id" => "2"
  "total" => null
]
```

I want a total is not null

Comment: Maybe because of $ before the total `$request->$total` to `$request->total`. But also make sure that the value actually exist too.

Comment: I tried it and the result is still the same

Comment: what ? that should be error, change the `$request->$total` to `$request->total` like Mr. Kenneth said, if that doesnt solve the problem, your variable name is wrong or maybe typo

Comment: Also check where `$request` comes from. If this is from blade or FE, check that `total` is correctly passed in the api or form submit.

Comment: I take a sum in one database column then add it with a request from the blade, I do this operation in the controller, then I want to add the results of the operation to the database. Like this $total = DB::table('pinjaman_logs')
                ->where('status', '=', 'approve')
                ->groupBy('user_id')
                ->sum('jumlah_pinjaman');
        $total += $request->jumlah_pinjaman;

Comment: maybe `'total' => $total` ?

Comment: it worked. thankyouuu

Answer (score 3):

```
'total' => $request->$total
```

should be

```
'total' => $total
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$total += $request->jumlah_pinjaman;

$data = [
    'tanggal' => $request->tanggal,
    'no_bukti' => $request->no_bukti,
    'jumlah_pinjaman' => $request->jumlah_pinjaman,
    'uraian' => $request->uraian,
    'user_id' => $request->user_id,

**//This will use the variable $total directly rather than trying
//to access it via the request object, as it seems you've already
//calculated the total with $total += $request->jumlah_pinjaman.**

    'total' => $total ? $total : 0  

];

dd($data);
```

Comment: also used the ternary operator 'total' => $total ? $total : 0 to handle null values.